# MySQL workbench does not display the tables

Tags: mysql

I installed mysql workbench in Windows7 32 bit machine. I imported a dump tables from another machine, the import process completes successfully as mysql shows. But, I can not see the tables, even after refresh all. Not only the tables that I import, even the tables in the test database (that comes by default) or any previously created tables in another database. Simply, it just shows the database name without the plus sign that display the tables. I removed mysql, installed it again, but no hope. I installed the requirements for mysql. What can be the reasons for such problem ?

Comment: how to you login in Workbench? `root` user?

Comment: It does not ask me for a user, but I assume it should be the root?

Answer (score 12):

If you're on mac, your object info and session section is covering the tables view. Just go ahead and drag that down and you should see the tables

[image]

Comment: Happens on Linux too. I was stuck on _Administration_ and I had to drag _Object info_ lower so I can see the _Administration_ and _Schemas_ tabs and switch to _Schemas_. What a horrible UX.

Comment: Thanks, you save my day 

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for this for years

Answer (score 5):

I had the same thing happen.  I just closed the program, re-opened it, and all the tables I imported were viewable.

Comment: hope they fix this.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue, table not showing up under Tables in the navigation sidebar in MySQL Workbench 6.0 even after exiting and relaunching MySQL Workbench. The solution was to right-click on Tables and Refresh All.

Comment: Using v6.3 on Mac osSierra (10.12.4), I was not able to get the right-click context menu on "Tables".  Others worked, however.  e.g.  Right-clicking on a schema displayed the "Edit Schema ..." menu.

Closing/re-opening also did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a bug in `MySql` Workbench.

If you cannot see any updated changes in `tables` or `schemas`, then simply close the workbench and reopen it.

If this does not work however, then check your connection and server status.

Answer (score 2):

I assume there is an icon (eye) next to your schema name, if you click on it it will open a window with all hidden tables. Click on show to solve the problem

[show hidden table in mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlY7i.png)

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is 8 years old at the time of writing this, I faced the same issue and thought I'd share my solution, which turned out to be rather basic: there's a refresh button to the right of 'Schemas'. If you click this, the newly created tables come into view. You don't have to close and reopen Mysql in such a case.

Comment: Having this issue in 2023 with the new SSO driver. Can't see a refresh butotn next to schemas in this version of build 125.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue, Decrease the window size of workbench, table will be visible.